# ¿Cómo referirse a las décadas de los siglos antepasados?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, tiempo

Para referirse a las décadas del siglo XX [se usan](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/en-los-anos-1970%C2%B4s-5573/) las siguientes formas: `los años veinte`, `la década de los 80`, `los cuarenta`, `los 20s`.

Pero ¿cómo referirse a las décadas de los siglos anteriores. Por ejemplo, si uno quiere comentar acerca de los años entre 1880 y 1889, ¿se puede escribir `los 80s del siglo XIX` o `los años ochenta del siglo XIX`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te contestas en el propio enlace que aportas en la pregunta

> Las formas apropiadas son **la década de 1970**, los setenta, los 70 y la década de los setenta, con números, si se menciona el año (1970), y con letras o números, si se mencionan solo sus dos últimas cifras (los setenta, los 70).

Date cuenta de que 1970 es el siglo pasado. Por esa regla podrías decir "la década de 1880".

Entiendo que algunas de esas formas (en ese artículo) aprovechan el contexto de "**el** siglo pasado" en lugar de "**un** siglo pasado (cualquiera)", pero puedes aplicar la misma norma.

- Durante la década de 1330 ...
- En el siglo XIV, durante la década de los treinta ...

De forma alternativa podrías decir "la primera (segunda o tercera...) década del siglo X."