# ¿Cómo expreso un intervalo de años al hablar?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, tiempo

Por ejemplo, si quiero decir "1995-2000", ¿debería decir "mil novecientos noventa y cinco a dos mil" u otra cosa?

Comment: ¿Podrías dar algo más de contexto? En muchas ocasiones el contexto hace que lo de "mil novecientos..." se sobreentienda. Recuerdo por ejemplo a un político que decía "en el quince" para hablar del 2015, lo que me resultó curioso pues normalmente el "dos mil" sí se dice.

Comment: Creo que deberías añadir ejemplos de uso (y al intentarlo posiblemente respondas parcialmente a tu pregunta). Si tu idioma principal no es el español, prueba a poner un par de ejemplos en inglés. El uso para intervalos de años no es tan distinto entre idiomas. Hay en el stack otras preguntas sobre como nombrar décadas, por ejemplo [¿Cómo referirse a las décadas de los siglos antepasados?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21326/5481) , [¿Cómo se llaman las primeras dos décadas del siglo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10629/5481) y https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21801/5481

Comment: No preguntabas por décadas @Diego. Creo que usaré ejemplos en inglés para preguntas en el futuro. ¡Buen consejo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para referirse a un intervalo de años, se puede utilizar la palabra "período", en cuyo caso se mencionarán los dos años, de inicio y fin, uno después del otro, por ejemplo:

- Durante el período mil novecientos noventa y cinco-dos mil, ...

Utilizando la palabra período o sin ella, pueden emplearse preposiciones, por ejemplo:

- **Entre** mil novecientos noventa y cinco **y** dos mil, ... ("y" es una conjunción)
- **De** mil novecientos noventa y cinco **a** dos mil, ...
- **Desde** mil novecientos noventa y cinco **hasta** dos mil, ...
- En/durante el período **entre** mil novecientos noventa y cinco **y** dos mil, ...
- En/durante el período **de** mil novecientos noventa y cinco **a** dos mil, ...
- En/durante el período **desde** mil novecientos noventa y cinco **hasta** dos mil, ...

Comment: no creo que el ejempo de "periodo" este correcto, el OP pregunta como "decir" y no creo que el guion no me parece pronunciable

Comment: En presentaciones, puede utilizarse la palabra período (u otra similar) aunque no esté escrita. El guion debe escribirse aunque no se pronuncie. Lo mismo ocurre con distancias o tramos espaciales: *el tramo Madrid-Valencia*